# Access Files from Android

Tags: server

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server, and I want to access and copy the files from my android phone to the server. I had try to look what is inside my `/run/user/1000/gvfs`, but it don't even have the `gvfs` folder.

I want to try to install Desktop GUI on the server, but my manager say if possible, don't install a GUI on the server.

I'm very new to Linux, just started it about one week ago, and have no idea how to continue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

is this installed

sudo apt-get install libmtp

are you connecting with USB

should be able to find with

mtp-detect
and
mtp-folders

Also, there are a few really good file browsers for the command line which you might find useful ...  like GNU Midnight Commander

Comment: When I use `sudo apt-get install libmtp` it said `E: Unable to locate package libmtp`.

Comment: And yes, I'm connecting with USB

Comment: `libmtp` is in every supported release of Ubuntu. If your system cannot locate it, that's a different problem. Use the 'Search' box at the top of every AskUbuntu page to see how others solved that problem.

Comment: maybe start by installing midnight commander and see if you are able to find the mtp drive (phone) visually.